# How to select div inside div inside div with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div id="tab">     
        <div class="" style="margin: 10px;">
            <div id="someVerylongId1" style="height: 400px; position: relative;">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="" style="margin: 10px;">
            <div id="someVerylongId2" style="height: 400px; position: relative;">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="" style="margin: 10px;">
            <div id="someVerylongId3" style="height: 400px; position: relative;">

            </div>
        </div>
<div>
```

I want to select all divs not specifying ids or checking any another attributes, is it possible to do like that?

Here is my try:

```
$("#tab div div")
```

but looks like is selecting not exactly correct. Need help.

The problem is, my selector returns more elements that it should

Comment: "....we need to go deeper!" :-P I guess `$("#tab > div > div")` should to the trick, not quite sure though.

Comment: Your selector is correct. Something else is wrong. Check that `$("#tab div div").length == 3`.

Comment: Check also if `$("#tab").length==1`

Comment: @WTK - to do that you would just do `if($('#tab').length)`. No need for the equals.

Comment: If it returns more elements then something else is wrong as I tested your code in jsfiddle and it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/9ZqYT/1/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$("div > div", "#tab");
```

That will select all children of divs using the context of #tab

http://jsfiddle.net/HenryGarle/mHpMM/

Comment: What is code when we use $(this) for parent element

Comment: That would depend on your selector but it would be something like $("div > div", $(this)). The second part of the call is the parent element, in the first example the parent was "#tab".

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
$("#tab > div > div")
```

You can use child selector (**>**) for select the child. See more info:
http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 2):

You could also use find method of JQuery. Find will return all the descendant elements of  the selected element.

$(selector).find(filter criteria)

ex:

$("div#tab").find("div")

Answer (score -3):

```
$("#tab").siblings();
```

[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)]

Quote from jquery:

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector.

Comment: This isn't what he was asking for.