# How to select child div within parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select html of class "postHandel" when I click replyBtn.
There are multiple "repost" divs, I want postHandel of the current div in which I am clicking replyBtn.

```
<div class="repost" data-id="52">
<div class="profileImg"></div>
<div class="postWrap">
    <div class="postUser">Tejas Kulkarni</div>
    <div class="postHandel">@tejas</div>
    <div class="postText"> </div> 
</div>
<a href="#" class="expandRP pull-right expandRP52" data-id="52"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></a>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="postOptions twtOptRP52">
    <ul>
        <li> <a class="btn btn-mini rtBtn" data-id="96"><i class="icon-retweet"></i> Repost</a></li>
        <li> <a class="btn btn-mini replyBtn" data-id="96"><i class="icon-reply"></i> Reply</a></li>
        <li> <a class="btn btn-mini favBtn" data-id="96"><i class="icon-star"></i> Fav</a></li>
        <li><div class="loadingPostsBtn hideme loadingBtn-96 hideme"><img src="http://linkzone.dev/assets/img/ajax-loader.gif"></div></li>
        <li><div class="loadingFailBtn hideme loadingFail-96 hideme"><img src="http://linkzone.dev/assets/img/ajax-fail.gif"></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My jQuery Code is :

```
 $(document).on("click",".replyBtn",function(){

    var postHandel = $(this).closest(".postWrap").html('');
    var log = $(postHandel).closest(".postHandel").html();
    console.log(log);

});
```

Comment: Is this markup repeated on your page or does it occur only once like you've shown?

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305175/how-to-select-div-inside-div-inside-div-with-jquery

Comment: code is missing a `</div>` I guess?

Comment: oops sorry, Bad copy paste </div> added with edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var log = $(this).closest(".repost").find(".postHandel:first").html();
```

Comment: this works but will not if there is more than one ".postHandel" elements which seems not to be the case here +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this)                            // current element (.replybtn)
  .closest('.report')              // up to main wrapper (top-most grouping element)
  .find('.postWrap > .postHandel') // down to postHandel
  .html();                         // the end value
```

You may not even need the `.postWrap >` discriminator, but it does make sure that it's the *that* `.postHandel` you're after.